# Error of healthCheck when the service is in IIS

Tags: c#, iis, .net-core, health-check

I'm using the healthCheck to verify the state of the services but I have an error when this service is in IIS.

In ConfigureServices:

```
services.AddHealthChecksUI(s =>
{
   s.AddHealthCheckEndpoint("Validations", "/CheckPoints");
}).AddInMemoryStorage();  

services.AddHealthChecks();
```

In Configure

```
  builder.MapHealthChecksUI(setupOptions: setup =>
  {
      setup.UIPath = "/CheckPointsUI";
  });
  builder.MapHealthChecks("/CheckPoints", new HealthCheckOptions()
  {
      Predicate = _ => true,
      ResponseWriter = UIResponseWriter.WriteHealthCheckUIResponse
  });
  builder.MapHealthChecks("/Status");
```

When I run the service in localhost all works good but the same code in IIS pool I have the next error:

> An invalid request URI was provided. The request URI must either be an absolute URI or BaseAdress must be set

I don't know why it behaves differently.

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce your problem, I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com.

Comment: I detected the possible error, is in this line:

`s.AddHealthCheckEndpoint("Validations", "/CheckPoints");`

If I add the absoluteUri in appsettings it works. In this moment only I have one variable, I don't know if I should add more variables there.